# Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter. I can not run my flutter project on iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, frameworks

Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5mas.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Hkw.png)

I tried:

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter upgrade
flutter build ios

and alse I removed Podfile

pod install
pod update

also I tried:

cd ios
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
flutter precache --ios
pod install

also:

cd ios
pod cache clean --all
flutter clean
flutter pub get

also did all steps in: https://phongyewtong.medium.com/how-to-fix-could-not-build-the-application-for-the-simulator-64444d4481a5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!
I did:
1- flutter channel beta
2- flutter upgrade
3- flutter run
4- flutter channel stable
5- flutter upgrade
6- flutter run

I hope it will be useful to someone